# Publish events directly to a topic in wso2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, ws-eventing, wso2-esb

I want to publish events directly to a topic in WSO2 ESB, rather going through an event mediator configured in a proxy or an API. I'm using WSO2 DSS as my event source. Is there any support or workaround on this?

Thanks in Advance